# Segmentation Fault in my code

Tags: c, algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

This is a code I submitted at sphere online judge for generating prime numbers but I'm getting a segmentation fault. The objective is to [generate prime numbers](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/PRIME1/) between the given range m to n (with n > m). This is implemented using the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm. Please tell me where im going wrong. Thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    long int m,n,c1,c2,c3;
    int t;

    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);


        //create prime list
        short int *prime;
        prime = (short int*)malloc((n-m)*sizeof(short int));

        //fill list with 0 - prime
        for(c1 = 2; c1 <= n; c1++){
                prime[c1] = 1;
        }

        //set 1 and 0 as not prime
        prime[0]=0;
        prime[1]=0;

        //find primes then eliminate their multiples (0 = prime, 1 = composite)
        for(c2 = 2;c2 <= (int)sqrt(n)+1;c2++){
            if(prime[c2]){
                c1=c2;
                for(c3 = 2*c1;c3 <= n; c3 = c3+c1){
                    prime[c3] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        //print primes
        for(c1 = m; c1 <=n; c1++){
            if(prime[c1]) printf("%d\n",c1);
        }
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, where is the segmentation fault occurring?

Comment: Do you have any information about where the segfault?  It's really hard to find a single bug in a huge block of code without some sort of hint as to where it might be.

Comment: use GDB and determine where segfault appears

Comment: I get a seg fault when m > n, you need to validate input, as others have stated

Comment: People, OP is talking about *online judge*. You don't get to know where the judge segfaulted. You don't even get to know the input data that judge uses to test your code.

Comment: @Dialecticus: even if the judges don't release that information, @jaykumarark can still run the program him/herself and see a segfault.

Answer (score 3):

`c3` can go up to `n` in the innermost loop, but you only may allocate less than `n` slots in your array.  In fact, even if you allocated `n` slots, index `n` would be one more than the number of slots you allocated.  At worst, you'd just corrupt some memory past the end of the array and hopefully not trash the stack.  At best, I guess you get a segfault.  You probably want to change your `X <= n` to `X < n` or allocate one more element in your array.  In fact, you probably should just allocate `(n + 1) * sizeof(short)` bytes for your array.

Also, you never set t and you never never validate the user input.  The latter may be okay if this is for a competition which would have constraints on input.  Also, you never free the `prime` array, so you have a memory leak.

Comment: Well the server is gonna compile the program so I assumed that t,m and n will be within the limits as specified in the user input section. Do I need to validate them ?

Comment: @jaymumarark: I missed where t was pulled from user input.  So m, n and t can go unverified, assuming that the judges have said they will not give you garbage input.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will you are allocating a memory which is (n-m) & you are acessing 
prime[n] ,

Answer (score 0):

Probably want to avoid this when prime is only 1 element long:

```
//set 1 and 0 as not prime
        prime[0]=0;
        prime[1]=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You malloc(n-m), but in the following loop you initialize prime[2..n]. *n-m* is at most 1E5, but *n* itself could be 1E9 (which is rather huge number). Your simple idea probably can not be implemented, because malloc(1E9) will probably fail. You need a smarter algorithm.